# ¿Que estoy haciendo mal al multiplicar los valores enteros del array en JS?

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

Tengo que realizar una función que tome un arreglo de números como parámetro y debo devolver el doble de cada elemento.

Yo estoy haciendo esto:

```
let arreglo1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
let arreglo2 = [1,2,4,8];

function agregarDoble(arreglo) {
    let doble = arreglo.map(x => {
        return x * 2;
    })
}
console.log(agregarDoble(arreglo1));
```

Lo cual el resultado en consola es "undefined" en la linea de console.log

Comment: le falta un `return doble` dentro de la función

Comment: Gracias @Emeeus por responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función efectivamente hace la multiplicación pero te falta devolver el resultado

```
let arreglo1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
let arreglo2 = [1,2,4,8];

function agregarDoble(arreglo) {
    let doble = arreglo.map(x => {
        return x * 2;
    });

    // agrega la siguiente línea
    return doble;
}
console.log(agregarDoble(arreglo1));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me dio el resultado que deseaba obtener!

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta, para dejar la publicacion lista.

Comment: Ver cómo [marcar la respuesta como aceptada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/182188)

Comment: Listo gente muchas gracias!!